# Xcode 4.2.1 for Snow Leopard

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

Is there a Xcode 4.2.1 for Snow Leopard that I can download if I am a registered developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The latest version of Xcode for Snow Leopard is version 4.2.

Comment: So when I am using Snow Leopard I can still submit Apps for the latest ios 5 version to Apple?

Comment: I haven't tried it but I don't know why not, since it uses the current iOS SDK.